# Angular2 - TypeScript : Adding an array to FormControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have validation Form using Angular 2 and want to add `ng2-select` to it

this is my code, Angular & HTML

```
submit.component.ts  

   . . .

  private city = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
   . . .

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMelks();

    this.addPropertyForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      . . .
      city: this.city,
     . . .
    });
  }
```

submit.component.html

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" [(ngModel)]="melk.city" placeholder="city" min="0" required>
 </div>
```

the code i want to add :

`Angular` :

```
  public city:Array<string> = ['NY','CA' ,'LA'];
```

`HTML` :

```
 <label>City</label>
      <ng-select [allowClear]="false"
                 [items]="city"
                 [disabled]="disabled"
                 (data)="refreshValue($event)"
                 (selected)="selected($event)"
                 (removed)="removed($event)"
                 (typed)="typed($event)"
                 placeholder="Choose the city">
      </ng-select>
```

Now how can i add ng2-select to my `input` and the the FormControl?

Comment: what do you want to do? It is not clear how you want to add select to an input...

Answer (score 1):

One workaround I've used is to create a hidden input right below ng-select and synced it with a ngModel. e.g.

```
 <label>City</label>
 <ng-select #cityModel
       [allowClear]="false"
       [items]="city"
       [disabled]="disabled"
       (data)="refreshValue($event)"
       (selected)="selected($event)"
       (removed)="removed($event)"
       (typed)="typed($event)"
       placeholder="Choose the city">
  </ng-select>
  <input [hidden]="true" type="text" [(ngModel)]="cityModel" name="cityModel" [formControl]="city">
```

submit.component.ts

```
   . . .

  private city = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
  private cityModel;

  . . .

  selected = (selectedCity) => {
      this.cityModel = value;
      this.city.markAsDirty();
  }
  removed = () => {
      this.cityModel = null;
      this.city.markAsDirty();
  }
```

Although this doesn't help if you do some action on the form control. Like `city.disable()` because you would be doing that on the hidden element instead.

I also have a PR to address this issue https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-select/pull/758

Answer (score 0):

try this, hopefully it's compatible with for formBuilder and allows you to grab current value:

```
<form class="form-group" [formGroup]="cityForm">
                <input class="form-control"formControlName="city" type="text" name="city" [(ngModel)]="melk.city" placeholder="city" min="0" required>



 <label>City</label>
      <ng-select formControlName="citySelect"
 [allowClear]="false"
                 [items]="city"
                 [disabled]="disabled"
                 (data)="refreshValue($event)"
                 (selected)="selected($event)"
                 (removed)="removed($event)"
                 (typed)="typed($event)"
                 placeholder="Choose the city">
      </ng-select>
 </form>
```